# Phonegap App: Shadows on clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

I am wondering if this is just the way html5 Apps are or can i fix this? To show you what i mean have a look at this:

[image]

This is what it looks like when i click on it on a device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your css :

```
* {
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); /* make transparent link selection, adjust last value opacity 0 to 1.0 */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

## CSS

```
a {border:none;outline:none;}
a img{border:none;outline:none;background:none;}
```